# How to make popup on the WooCommerce listing page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a WooCommerce website where I want to have a pop-up when someone clicks on apply now button. There I want to have two fields 1) All the class(custom field) that product has. 2) Kids that the current logged in user has.
And there would be Add to Cart button which would add the item inside the cart.

I have successfully been able to get those on my product page. I am using toolset https://toolset.com to create my product listing page and single product page.

This is my code for a single product list (Template View)

```
<div class="school">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="image">
      [types field="logo"][/types]
      </div>
      <div class="city">
        <img src="link_to_img">
        [types field="city"][/types]
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
      <p>[wpv-post-title]</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        [wpv-post-read-more]
      <button class="applynow" href="#">Apply Now</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also this is the code to render those fields 1 & 2 in the popup. I am using this in my single product page.

```
function iconic_output_engraving_field() {
    global $product;
    $classes = get_post_meta($product->get_id(),'wpcf-classes-opened-for-admission',array('show_name' => 'true'));
    print_r("<label>Select Class</label>");
    print_r("<select name='class'>");
    print_r("<option disabled selected value> -- Select a Class -- </option>");
    foreach ($classes as $class) {
     print_r( "<option value='".$class[0]."'>".$class[0]."</option>");
    }
    print_r("</select>");
    $args = array(
    'id' => 1538,
    );
    echo render_view( $args );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'iconic_output_engraving_field', 10 );
```

How can I pass the id through the button, so that I can create a template which loads up with correct data and Add to Cart button.

Comment: What is the listing page, what are you displaying in listing page can you please share your web link or any screenshots to know.

Comment: Screenshot for listing : https://nimb.ws/tWr1Rj

Answer (score 0):

> > https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-login-woocommerce/

This plugin does what you're looking for, BUT it uses wp_user_login or some other function that you would need to change.

Basically, download, check the code of the plugin, your answer should be there.

> > Plugin is to create a popup when a button is clicked, plugin uses it to login/register, but you could edit to do whatever.